# If $f(\mathbb{R})$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, is it continuous or differentiable

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm doing a practice paper before my exam and I came across the following question, but I don't have the memo. I know if a function is differentiable then it it must continuous, so that rules out choice C. Other than that, I don't know how to answer this. I'm assuming it's continuous the answer is D but I'm really uncertain

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathbb{Q}$. Then:

A. $f$ is not continuous.

B. $f$ is continuous but not differentiable.

C. $f$ is differentiable but not continuous.

D. $f$ is differentiable and monotonic.

E. $f$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is constant.

Comment: Hint: if you have more than one rational number in $f(\mathbb R)$, there is an irrational number between them.  But you could have just one...

Comment: I think you must have mis-copied the question. It should ask: Which of the following is necessarily true? (And the answer is E.)

Comment: Use the fact that the image of a connected set under a continuous function is also connected.

Answer (score -1):

A. $f$ is not continuous since for conrinuous functions $f(\Bbb R)$ is an interval, but $\Bbb Q$ is not the interval.

D. Yes, if $f$ is a constant function. For nonconstant ones this is false.

E. True.

Comment: That's wrong $-$ $f$ might be continuous (if it is constant). See my comment to the OP.

Comment: E. If $f$ is continuous, then the image $f(\Bbb R)$ is connected. The only connected subsets of rationals are singletons. Then $f$ is necessarily constant. The opposite implication is obvious.

Comment: We're considering all functions satisfying this. It may be continuous, so A is wrong, and it may not be continuous, so D is wrong.